# __subclasses__() usage when using multiple py files

Tags: python

```
# test1.py
class DatabaseEngine(object):
    pass

# test2.py
from test1 import DatabaseEngine
class OracleEngine(DatabaseEngine):
    pass

# test3.py
from test1 import DatabaseEngine
class MysqlEngine(DatabaseEngine):
    pass

# test4.py
# try 1
from test1 import DatabaseEngine
print DatabaseEngine.__subclasses__() # returns empty list 

# try 2
from test2 import DatabaseEngine
from test3 import DatabaseEngine
print DatabaseEngine.__subclasses__() # returns [oracle, mysql]
```

Why does #try1 fails to recognize the subclasses but #try 2 recognizes its sub classes.

I want to use __ subclasses() __ in test4.py without doing

```
from test2 import DatabaseEngine
from test3 import DatabaseEngine
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: WHAT subclasses?  If you did not at some point import test2.py and test3.py, then the subclasses they declare do not exist - or were you expecting Python to search every .py file on your hard disk, looking for such declarations?  Note that you could write it as simply `import test2, test3` - the `DatabaseEngine` they contain is exactly the same as the one you can import directly from test1.

Comment: @jasonharper. Thanks. I understand. I am trying to create a factory pattern where a factory will create a db engine based on the type I provide. Instead of hardcoding the different class names as a List to create an object based on the type I provide, I wanted to programmatically get the sub classes of all the base class and loop and get the object I need. So later,  If I wanted to add mysql engine, then I thought, creating a sub class from `DatabaseEngine``` and providing the type as mysql from my client will get me a mysql engine.

Comment: @jasonharper Currently, the factory class has a list of the engine objects it can create. Eg [‘OracleClassName’] . Now if I have to add mysql, then I have to make code changes to the factory to support it.

Comment: If the clients have to specify which engine they want, they might as well call the subclass directly - `OracleEngine(username, password)` or whatever.  A factory function with knowledge of all the available classes only really makes sense here if it is going to decide which class to use, itself.  (And note that unless you've actually imported all the class definitions, THERE IS NO NAME by which you can refer to them!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 1 doesn't work b/c importing explicitly evaluates the code in that module. You do not import the modules containing your subclasses in try 1, so they do not get evaluated.

If you choose to keep your subclasses in different modules and want access them all, then there will have to be at least one module where you import them all.

I'd recommend creating another file containing your subclass implementations, importing them there, then when you need the subclasses, import this one file.